# Gulp and absolute path

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

I am new in Gulp.
I was wondering if I could have an absolute path for source like the code below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('hello', function() {
    return gulp.src(['C:\a\b\c\css\fonts.css',
    'C:\a\b\c\css\common.css',
    'C:\a\b\c\css\generic.css'])
    .pipe(concat('stylestest.css'))
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('web'));
});
```

If not, is it possible to put gulp project and web application next to each other, instead of putting web application inside the gulp project directory.
Actually, I don't want to change current structure of my project but I see people copy app inside gulp project folder.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. I am not sure if I am doing right.

Comment: No error but no output

Comment: `'\'`  is not a valid character in javascript, try `'\\'` for backslash.

Answer (score 0):

By giving `C:\a\b\c\css\fonts.css'` absolute path won't help you in integration, test and live branch.

I would recommend you to put gulp file parallel to the project folder and that is what gulp is also recommending.

Have a look below github link for reference :

https://github.com/varit05/gulp-build

I hope it helps you!

Cheers!